# Port Virtualenv based app error

Tags: python, virtualenv

For the last couple of weeks I have programmed a flask server. I was adviced to use virtualenv to make sure that all my python dependencies are easily tracked. However, now I have deployed it on my test server and it gives me the following error:

```
from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Which is about the first python module that I have installed. Is there something I am doing wrong here? Virtualenv should've taken care for this, right? How can I check for these kind of errors during development?

Comment: You probably installed flask *before* you invoke the virtualenv. You have to `pip install` all your required packages within virtualenv.

Comment: I installed Flask before, yes. However, flask is installed in the venv/lib/python-2.7/sit-packages directory. So I think its some kind of path error.

Comment: Within your virtualenv: Run python and check if `import sys; sys.path` contains your  venv/lib/python-2.7/sit-packages.

Comment: There is a /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages in there but not a /venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages. Guess thats the problem?

Comment: Have you activated your virtualenv? You have to do that whenever you open a new terminal.

Comment: just by . venv/bin/activate right? I did that

Comment: That should activate it. Here a link to a tutorial for virtualenv http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ Have a look

Comment: How can I make sure that my path does contain a pointer to the /venv/ environment? Anyone?

Comment: Just to be clear: Have you installed virtualenv on your test server, too? To just deploy your project with the venv directory and call `. venv/bin/activate` does not suffice.

Comment: I have installed virtualenv. Does not make any